# How to retrieve document data in Firebase without knowing collection name?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The structure of my Firebase data is `<collection>/<document>`.

I know the name of the document, how can I access its data without specifying the collection name (unknown).

Some state that a Snapshot is needed and then `getParent()` can be called, the problem is in order to obtain a Snapshot you need the name of the collection.

The following works:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance.collection("Fruit").doc("Apples").get()
```

Suppose we don't know that the collection's name is "Fruit", how can we still access the Document's data OR how can we retrieve its associated collection name?

Comment: Please edit the question to more specifically state what you know, along with any code you have so far that we can follow along with.  The problem as stated is too abstract right now.  Strictly speaking, if all your know is a document ID string, you can't know anything about what collection it might be in without first querying he collection to see if it exists.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited my question as you've asked from me, do you know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments, if all you know is the string ID of a document, there is no way to know if it exists in any collection.  It's important to know that there can be any number of collections with a document of a particular ID - the IDs are not unique across the entire database.

If you want to know if a document exists in a collection, you have to do exactly what you are showing now: get the document and check the snapshot to see if it exists.  There are no workarounds for this.  If you are storing these IDs somewhere, consider also storing the name of the collection (or the full path to the document) so that you have a reliable way of getting it back.

Comment: And what if "Fruit" is the (only) root collection of the database inside that particular app, is there a way to retrieve the root collection id "Fruit" (using either the document ID or another way)?

Comment: No, that's not possible.